# Changing datetime format in Python Language

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am parsing emails through Gmail API and have got the following date format:

```
Sat, 21 Jan 2017 05:08:04 -0800
```

I want to convert it into ISO `2017-01-21` (yyyy-mm-dd) format for MySQL storage. I am not able to do it through strftime()/strptime() and am missing something. Can someone please help?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

isoformat() in the dateutil.

```
import dateutil.parser as parser
text = 'Sat, 21 Jan 2017 05:08:04 -0800'
date = (parser.parse(text))
print(date.isoformat())
print (date.date())
```

Output :

2017-01-21T05:08:04-08:00
 2017-01-21

Comment: Thanks... but I need only the date... not time

Comment: print (date.date()) . This gives u just the date

Comment: Yes!... that's what I want. Thanks @saranya

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `strptime()`:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('Sat, 21 Jan 2017 05:08:04 -0800', '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z')
```

That gives you:

```
datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 21, 5, 8, 4, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(-1, 57600)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime 
s="Sat, 21 Jan 2017 05:08:04 -0800"
d=(datetime.strptime(s,"%a, %d %b %Y %X -%f"))
print(datetime.strftime(d,"%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Output : 2017-01-21

Comment: Thanks. But it is throwing the following error:

`ValueError: time data 'Sat, 21 Jan 2017 05:08:04 -0800' does not match format '%a %d %b %Y %X -%f'`

Comment: @chhibbz sorry!!.Edited comma missing

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it manually using simple split and dictionary.That way, you will have more control over formatting.

```
def dateconvertor(date):
    date = date.split(' ')
    month = {'Jan': 1, 'Feb': 2, 'Mar': 3}
    print str(date[1]) + '-' + str(month[date[2]]) + '-' + str(date[3])

def main():
    dt = "Sat, 21 Jan 2017 05:08:04 -0800"
    dateconvertor(dt)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Keep it simple.